# Python boto3 checking for valid bucket within region

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have seen examples for checking whether an S3 bucket exists and have implemented them below. My bucket is located in us-east-1 region but the following code doesn't throw an exception. Is there a way to make the check region specific depending on my session?

```
session = boto3.Session(
    profile_name = 'TEST'
    ,region_name='ap-south-1'
)

s3 = session.resource('s3')

bucket_name = 'TEST_BUCKET'

try:
    s3.meta.client.head_bucket(Bucket = bucket_name)
except ClientError as c:
    print(c)
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to hard-code the region in code anyway. boto3 will use the [configuration](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#overview) from the system via the environment, config files, profile, etc. It's probably more flexible to configure the region in one of those places.

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Do you need to know whether the bucket exists (anywhere), or do you need to know in which region the bucket exists? Please note that bucket names are _globally unique_.

Comment: The hard-codded region was just for testing purposes. The user will supply the region they want to use.

I wanted to make sure the bucket existed before trying to transfer a file. I was not aware that bucket names are globally unique so that helps.

Thank you both for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter which S3 regional endpoint you send the request to. The underlying SDK (boto3) will redirect as needed. It's preferable, however, to target the correct region if you know it in advance, to save on redirects.

You can see this in detail if you use the awscli in debug mode:

```
aws s3api head-bucket --bucket mybucket --region ap-south-1 --debug
```

You will see debug output similar to this:

```
DEBUG - S3 client configured for region ap-south-1 but the bucket mybucket is in region us-east-1; Please configure the proper region to avoid multiple unnecessary redirects and signing attempts.
DEBUG - Switching signature version for service s3 to version s3v4 based on config file override.
DEBUG - Updating URI from https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket to https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket
```

Note that the awscli uses the boto3 SDK, as does your Python script.